# (GCMC - windows) git credential manager core keeps prompting for password (gitlab repo)

Tags: git

Following a change of my gitlab account password I'm running into troubles to set my credential helper.
I uninstalled my previous git for windows version and installed the latest one including Git Credential Manager Core.

I'm using Android Studio and manage to fetch / pull / push through the IDE. Since I installed this new version of git for windows, a prompt is showing up every now and then. Worse, sometimes when I perfom a git operation my account gets blocked due to company policy (following multiple call with wrong password I guess).

I tried to set my credential helper to `manager`, `manager-core` but with no luck. I used to add entries into the windows authentication manager but they get removed from it, don't know by whom.

My remote repo is set with a https URL.

So my question is : how do I set GCMC to ask my password when my password has expired and cache the new one I'm givin ?

I've red a bit about GCMC but can't find the answer, this is crazy that new stuff are actually more complicated and buggy than older tools today deprecated (was working fine with wincred for example).

Comment: I'm having the same problem here with my credentials being lost every day... this is pretty annoying

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using an access token. I made a small doc (in French, sorry).

## Contexte

Depuis la version **v2.29.0**, git for windows préconise l'utilisation de `GCMC - Git Credential Manager Core -` en remplacement de "Git Credential Manager" (deprecated) :

> Important note: v2.29.0 and v2.29.1 upgrade existing users of Git Credential Manager for Windows (which was just deprecated) to Git Credential Manager Core ("GCM Core", which is the designated successor of the former). This is necessary because GitHub deprecated password-based authentication and intends to remove support for it soon, and GCM Core is prepared for this change."

## Installation

1. Dans les étapes d'installation de git for Windows, sélectionner `Git Credential Manager Core`

## Configuration

1. Une fois l'installation effectuée, ouvrir un bash git et valider que la commande `git config credential.helper` retourne bien `manager-core`
2. Se rendre dans le **gestionnaire d'identification Windows** et supprimer les éventuelles entrées existantes vers `git:https://git.xxxx`
3. Dans les settings gitlab, générer un access token (name : `personal access token`)
4. Dans le répertoire d'un projet clôné depuis git, réaliser un `git pull / fetch / push`
5. Une modale s'ouvre, renseigner alors en **login** : `personal access token`, **password** : `le token nouvellement créé`
6. Valider l'ajout de la nouvelle entrée dans le **gestionnaire d'identification Windows** avec comme login `personal access token`
7. Si votre IDE (testé avec IntelliJ / Android Studio) demande une authentification, cocher `Use credential manager`

## Debug

En cas de problème et pour activer le debug ouvrir une invite de commande et taper :

```
setx GIT_TRACE %userprofile%\git.log
setx GCM_TRACE %userprofile%\git.log
setx GCM_TRACE_SECRETS 1 (attention, des informations sensibles seront visibles dans le log - access token -)
```

Après utilisation via git bash / IDE un fichier `git.log` devrait donc être présent dans votre répertoire %userprofile% (ce n'est pas instantané)

### Extrait de log :

```
[RunAsync] Tracing of secrets is enabled. Trace output may contain sensitive information.
[RunInternalAsync] Git Credential Manager version X (Windows, .NET Framework X) 'store'
[ExecuteAsync] Start 'store' command...
[ExecuteAsync] Detecting host provider for input:
[ExecuteAsync]  protocol=https
[ExecuteAsync]  host=git.xxxx
[ExecuteAsync]  username=personal access token
[ExecuteAsync]  password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  <-------- votre access token
[GetProvider] Performing auto-detection of host provider.
[ExecuteAsync] Host provider 'Generic' was selected.
[StoreCredentialAsync] Storing credential with service=https://git.xxxx account=personal access token...
[StoreCredentialAsync] Credential was successfully stored.
[ExecuteAsync] End 'store' command...
```

Pour désactiver le debug :
supprimer les variables d'environnement `GIT_TRACE`, `GCM_TRACE`, `GCM_TRACE_SECRETS`

Comment: Just perfect information, very clear and following the steps solved the problem for me (I'm using SSO on a private GitLab instance).

Answer (score 1):

Apr. 2022: The [latest GCM v2.0.692](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/releases/tag/v2.0.692) does officially support GitLab GUI prompt.

See [PR 621](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/pull/621):

> Add GUI prompts on all platforms for GitLab authentication. GUI prompts are required because if GCM/Git is invoked from an IDE without a terminal, there is no way for the user to authenticate for GitLab.
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5658207/156394932-8f40f33e-f4e4-4460-9380-54f46b82168a.png]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was setting credential.useHttpPath to true and enabling the interactive mode.

By setting credential.useHttpPath to true, GCM will keep the host name of the git URL as the key on the credential store. So once you authinticate one time using PAT. it saves the access token under the host key. So GCM won't ask to authenticate again.

Enabling interactive mode is just optional. If this is set to true, you won't need a PAT. Just signing to the git organization (azure devops/ github/ etc.) will be enough.

```bash
git config --global credential.useHttpPath true
git config credential.interactive true
```

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70268862) for more references